# create dynamic asp.net button in code behind but render in specific place on aspx page

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, controls

Creating a dynamic button in code behind as:

```
Dim b As Button = New Button()
b.Text = "Some Dynamic Text Here"
b.PostBackUrl = "some_page.asx"
```

I want to be able to render that in a specific location on an aspx page.

In aspx page, I want to do:

```
<td>
<%
If (specific condition) Then
    'render that specific button here <---------
Else
    'render something else
End If 
%>
</td>
```

1 - I know of being able to do a

```
Page.Form.Controls.Add(dynamic button here)
```

but I can not add it into a specific place on the page (not even with CSS because the button will go into a table -- the table has a column of numbers where if non zero, a button will show that crosspage postback to show drilldowned items)

Comment: In general, working with dynamic controls gets icky-sticky and Viewstate can become a large problem. I'd highly recommend hiding/showing controls with the `Visible` property, even if you group them into another control, such as an `asp:Panel`.

Comment: But how do you dynamically set the text for the static button you are creating?

Comment: using an `asp:Button` or `asp:LinkButton`, `myButton.Text = "blahblah";` , just like you did above.

Comment: Right, but how do I reference the specific button being created? In aspx page, done <asp:Button runat="server" ID="<%= some_dynamic_value_here %>"> is not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a placeholder where you want the button to be

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="placeHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

And add the button in the code

```
If (specific condition) Then   
    placeHolder.Controls.Add(b)
```

Comment: I've seen the method/approach, but how, in the code behind, do I reference the placeholder? I need to be able to create placeholders with a dynamic id so in the codebehind, i can add it to the correct placeholder

Comment: So you want dynamic placeholders with dynamic buttons? I think you need to find a simpler solution

Comment: Would you be able to suggest one? For looking at a report table, for a number <> 0, to see that specific data (ie. 7/1/2011, 100 widgets; 7/2/2011, 0 widgets) 100 widgets would be clickable.  I could create a URL with query string to pass the values to retrieve those 100 widgets but cross-page postback seems like the better solution (since I won't have to parse a string for values etc)

Comment: Bind to an asp:Repeater control and put the button/data inside its item template

Comment: After reviewing the repeater control, it seems the issue still occurs where I will not be able to create a button that has a dynamic ID when putting it into the item template... I think the solution I am going to do (attempt) is (just came up with it now) create an html button, set the id dynamically, add javascript so when it is clicked it changes the form location and submits the form so it posts it to the page I want it cross-page postbacked to... "Winning!"

Comment: THE REASON WHY THIS ANSWER WAS MARKED AS THE SOLUTION IS BECAUSE OF MY COMMENT DIRECTLY ABOVE BEING THE WAY TO SOLVE IT!

Basically create an html button, onclick (or unobtrusive js) set a hidden form field to the value you are trying to uniquely identify and then change the location of where the form is submitted to.  Then, on the second page check the value of that hidden form field to determine button pressed and have all the cool things of being able to access previous page controls (as I needed since I wanted to open a new page and grab data from previous page's control for sql filters)

Comment: Ok, so after setting the hidden form field values, and posting to the next page, you might get an error saying something like .. invalid viewstate, if web farm or cluster do not use auto generate ... to fix that, you set page-level directive of <%@ Page EnableViewStateMac="false" %> (this has some side effects).. then, after that .. you get access to your form values using Request.Form("id here") because you can not set a PreviousPage directive and/or use/find previous page controls... FINISHED